# How to add padding or margin to a relative container with absolute children

Tags: html, css, position, padding, absolute

I have a horizontally scrollable container with two rows of elements inside. They are absolutely positioned with spacing between them. The top, left, and bottom padding of this structure works fine. However, the right size is not respecting any CSS I throw at it. The rightmost child elements touch the edge of the container and will not allow any space. I need to accomplish this without having such space obscure the child elements as the scroll toward that edge.

I know that I can achieve this with JavaScript. Though, I would rather take advantage of HTML/CSS where possible.

Demo: http://codepen.io/jneander/pen/ByVQMR

*JavaScript*

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("list")[0];
var add = document.getElementsByClassName("add")[0];

function setPosition(li, index) {
  li.innerText = index + 1;
  li.style.top = 10 + (index % 2) * 50 + "px";
  li.style.left = 10 + Math.floor(index / 2) * 50 + "px";
}

function reorder() {
  for (var i = 0; i < list.children.length; i++) {
    setPosition(list.children[i], i);
  }
};

function addItem() {
  var count = list.children.length;
  var li = document.createElement("div");
  li.classList.add("item");
  li.innerText = count + 1;
  setPosition(li, count);
  li.onclick = function() { li.remove(); reorder() }
  list.appendChild(li);
};

add.onclick = function() {
  addItem();
};

for (var i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
  addItem();
}
```

*CSS*

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mr-boddy {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 3rem;
  width: 500px;
  height: 110px;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list {
  height: 130px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.list .item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background: lavender;
  display: block;
}

.add {
  margin-left: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  background: #9C9;
  border: none;
}
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="mr-boddy">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="list">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="add">Add</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

If it's ok to "cut-off" part of the boxes, add padding to the outer container instead of the boxes inside:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

If you want the initial 20 items to appear within the container (not cut off by the padding), then increase the width of .mr-boddy (e.g. 510px).

Comment: The clipping you mention is one thing I need to avoid. Though, the appearance rendered when list is scrolled to reveal the rightmost elements (with 10px of space between the last box and the right edge) is the ultimate goal here.